# AngularJs is removing response headers before passing to my controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the situation:

I made a post request to the server to create an item, and expect it to return "201 Created" with the new item location in the Location Header, where I get it to make a second request and get full item data.

These are the response headers sent by the server:

```
Status Code: 201 Created
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 17
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Thu, 22 Sep 2016 08:52:20 GMT
Location: /tasks/4
access-control-allow-headers: Content-type, Cache-Control, Keep-Alive, Location
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST, PUT, DEL, OPTIONS
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Content-type, Cache-Control, Keep-Alive, Location
```

Then, when I try to get the Location header from My controller, I get:

```
// console.log(response.headers)
[content-type,] { content-type="application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

in my firefox console, and it throws an error if I try to do:

```
response.headers['Location']
```

Note: I'm using Angular 1.5.8 and the recommended "Promise" variant for $https

Here is an excerpt of my controller code:

```
  app.controller('NewTaskCtrl', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.taskName = null
  $scope.createTask = function(){
    var data=JSON.stringify( { Name: $scope.taskName} )
    $http.post('http://192.168.1.129:9999/api/tasks',data)
    .then(
      function(response){
        // error Here  => console.log('Received Headers', response.headers)
        console.log('Received Headers', response.headers())
        // Error here => $http.get('http://192.168.1.129:9999'+response.headers['Location'])
        $http.get('http://192.168.1.129:9999'+response.headers('Location'))
        .then (
          function(response){
            $scope.Tasks.push(response)
          },
          function(reason){
            alert("Unexpected Error Ocurred:\n"+JSON.stringify(reason))
          }
        )
      },
      function(reason){
        alert("Unexpected Error Ocurred:\n"+JSON.stringify(reason))
      }
    )
  }
})
```

Any idea of why I'm losing the headers and how I can get them?

EDIT. I commented the offending line and put the correct on its place, for the records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
response.headers('Location')
```

Instead of

```
response.headers['Location']
```

As headers is a function, not an object.

Comment: I feel stupid right now. Anyway, lot's of thanks for your time and your answer